# How to calculate distance from motion of video?

Tags: computer-vision

I am trying to find how far away a point in an image is from a single camera. The data I have is a video and the camera intrinsics. Is it possible to accurately calculate distance with just this?

So far I have tried picking points and tracking those points through the video. When it finishes the points that are closer to me traveled more pixels than the ones that are farther. There is defiantly a relation here with how far it is and how much it moves but I cant seem to translate that to a distance?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, provided the point of interest does not move with respect to the camera. The distance can be estimated up to an unknown scale, that you can resolve by identifying in the scene an object of known physical size.
Research terms: "match-moving", "structure from motion", "bundle adjustment"